# Dynamically load IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Is is possible to load SI flow definitions at runtime? I know I can do something like `@ImportResource("/integration/integration.xml")` and it will load the definitions at startup. The question is: can I load such files at runtime? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended modern way to do that is exactly about an `IntegrationFlow` and Java DSL.
See more info in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

If you still stuck with XML configuration, you probably need to take a look into this extension: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow

If that is not enough, you may do something like `GenericXmlApplicationContext` and point to your XML config. Also see its `setParent(ApplicationContext)` if you need relationship with the current application context.